# Minimum Spanning Tree of set of nodes in a complete graph

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

[image]

I am trying to find the minimum spanning tree connecting the dots but by respecting the existing layout of the network. I am having difficulty formulating the network in python's tool networkx to find the minimum spanning tree.

I need to find the minimum spanning tree covering only the dots, Considering that I have the coordinates of those points and I can find the length of the lines that connect them.

Any pointers or ideas on how to do this?

Comment: This doesn't look like it's really a complete graph (everyone connected to everyone), and it's not clear you actually want a spanning tree (a tree which contains all nodes of the graph).  Can you clarify?

Comment: Do you maybe want the minimum length of roads that still connects all dots? If so, this probably reduces to some variant of the traveling salesman problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are solving the [Steiner tree problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem), which is NP-hard. `networkx` provides an approximation algorithm to solve this problem: [networkx.algorithms.approximation.steinertree.steiner_tree](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.approximation.steinertree.steiner_tree.html).